# What's the better way to make closable QPushButton?

Tags: qt

That is something like closable tabs in QTabBar.

Ready:::::::::::::::::::::

```
BtnWithClosing::BtnWithClosing(QString txt, QWidget *parent):
QPushButton(txt, parent) {
  QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
  layout->setMargin(4);
  layout->setSpacing(0);
  layout->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetMaximumSize);
  setText(text() + "    "); // for close button space
  QPushButton *btnClose = new QPushButton;
  btnClose->setStyleSheet("QPushButton:hover {image:"
    "url(:/images/closebtnover.png);}"
    "QPushButton {image: url(:/images/closebtn.png); margin-right: -9;"
    "margin-left: -6; min-width: 0; background-color: transparent;"
    "min-height: 0; border-width: 0px; border-radius: 9px; padding: 0px;}");
  layout->addWidget(btnClose, 0, Qt::AlignRight);
  setLayout(layout);
}
```

Comment: It looks good fom there. What you mean by "look very bad"?

Comment: I don't know how to fill the frame with buttons entirely so to make it look like one solid button.

Comment: 1) Show you code. 2) Show screenshot of your app. 3) Draw screenshot that you expect to get.

Comment: And I want close button look small and round. So I think only way to paint on QPushButton and catch mouse events. How can I do this? Thanx for any reference!

Comment: I don't know how insert image here. But believe, it looks like small squares in big square or something like this...

Comment: When editing the question, look for the picture icon in the editor's toolbar. It's a little rectangle picture.